# Disable flash in Youtube for Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have created a webview in Android as follows

```
String target_url="https://m.youtube.com/";
webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "YTVID");
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl(target_url);
```

In web browser, the Videos are loaded in HTML5 Video tag. But in Android webview, it opens the videos in Flash mode.

Is there any option to force the videos in HTML5 or to DISABLE flash in Android Webview.

Tried this but no use

`webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.OFF);`

Also set PluginState is now depreciated

Comment: Why not use youtube api :D

Comment: @edwinj I can use, But using webview with youtube mobile website is my requirement now. That is the reason I am looking for this.